# What should be the addresses in CSS (for links&images)

Tags: html, css, image, url, hyperlink

In my website the menu is loaded from a file called "menu.php". 
But my website has some sub-directories  - /blog/ , /searchtool/, /shop/

They are with the same design, using the same CSS file. 
But the urls for the images and for the links are like this:

```
<a href="my-page.html" >
<img src="images/my-image.jpg" >Image description</a>
```

If I add my website full URL before them - it works

```
<a href="http://example.com/my-page.html" >
<img src="http://example.com/images/my-image.jpg" />Image description</a>
```

My question is how does this affect my website performance?
Is it good or bad?
What problems can it cause?

Is there anything I should know before doing it?

**How about using "../" before the addresses, will it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sorts of SEO problems on the web are caused by the use of `relative URLs` in links, canonicals and more.

An `absolute URL` contains more information than a relative URL does. `Relative URLs` are more convenient because they are shorter and often more portable. However, you can `use them only to reference links on the same server as the page that contains them`

`Relative URLs` are often used because developers have a test environment on another hostname and it makes it easy for them to move stuff between their test environment and their live environment. Other reasons include that it’s `“just easier in website maintenance”`. They’re also, in my opinion falsely, promoted by some websites about site speed because `they’re “shorter” and thus “faster”.`

have a good read here [relative-urls-issues](http://yoast.com/relative-urls-issues/)

Answer (score 2):

**It depends.**

The performance gain from using relative URLs is absolutely negligible compared to using absolute URLs. Of course, it is recommended to use relative URLs where you can, for example, the content residing on your own server within folders, which you can link easily.

The browsers are efficient enough to resolve relative URLs and as I said, it gives you no major performance increase as such. To answer your question, it is generally a common practice to use relative linking if you are referring to resources on your servers.

One could argue that using absolute URLs could cause a subtle decrease in load time as there will be a touch more DNS lookups, but don't worry, its so minimal it won't even matter. But always, use relative resource referencing where you can, its just less fussier.

> Reasons for using Relative URLs

1. Easier to debug issues on localhost
2. Migrating to a different server like from Bluehost to Hostgator
3. Easier to work with shorter paths for development reasons
4. Helpful in developing on multiple environment

> Reasons for using Absolute URLs

1. From a SEO standpoint,its better.Offers canonicalization
2. For search engines, doesn't matter really. They resolve relative well enough too.

Comment: If that resource is on your server, you can link it.